# Applying C compiler CFLAGS when building Python native extensions with setup.py

Tags: python, gcc, setup.py

I am building an app for OSX, currently I am getting `Illegal Instruction 4` error messages when running the application. One SOF question suggested adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7` to the build options.

How do I do this with my current command:

```
python setup.py bdist_dmg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distutils` adds the contents of the `CFLAGS` environment variable to the compilation command, so just set that variable:

```
CFLAGS=-mmacosx-version-min=10.7 python setup.py bdist_dmg
```